# How can you re-focus the first selected row in the WPF DataGrid when it gains focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

Simple question with an as-of-yet unfound answer.  We have a WPF DataGrid on our window which supports multi-select.  Say it has ten items in it and you have items six through ten selected.  If you tab away from the control, when the control gets focus again, the first item is focused but not selected.  The selection still remains on items six through ten. This is made worse for us because we hide the focus rectangle, instead relying on the selection highlight, which is what the user would expect to happen.

I've tried responding to the IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged event as shown here, including with and without the dispatcher, figuring maybe something else was changing it after the fact, but still no avail.

```
private void TestDataGrid_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!(bool)e.NewValue)
        return;

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        var firstSelectedItem = VariableValuesDataGrid.SelectedItem;

        if(firstSelectedItem != null)
            VariableValuesDataGrid.CurrentItem = firstSelectedItem;
    }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: So you want the first item to be selected and focused if your data-grid gets the focus, right?

Comment: Close. I want the first selected row to be focused.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really that familiar with the WPF DataGrid but I suspect you must be dealing with the same issues of the old forms DataGridView.

Setting the selected row only highlights and doesn't actually focus it. And the `CurrentRow` property is unfortunately private but the `CurrentCell` property is not and can be used to set the selection instead.

```
myDataGrid.CurrentCell = myDataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0];
myDataGrid.Rows[i].Selected = True;
```